# how to get input text from SearchView xamarin android?

Tags: xamarin.android

How to get input text from SearchView xamarin android?
I'm try searchView.GetQuery but error No Suggestions.

```
    searchView.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
            searchView.QueryTextChange += SearchView_QueryTextChange;
            searchView.QueryTextSubmit += SearchView_QueryTextSubmit;
            /*Error*/
            //searchView.GetQuery
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some differences between native Android and Xamarin.Android .

You just need to call **searchView.Query;** because it is a property in Xamarin (in native Android it is a method).

```
searchView.QueryTextChange += SearchView_QueryTextChange;
```

```
private void SearchView_QueryTextChange(object sender, SearchView.QueryTextChangeEventArgs e)
{
   var searchView = sender as SearchView;
   var text = searchView.Query;
}
```